# Не правильно работает подсветка синтаксиса в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Почему метод `Update` подсвечивается синим цветом, а `Start` - жёлтым?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чём именно неправильность?

Comment: @ganz, на первый взгляд не понятно почему имена двух методов раскрашены по разному

Comment: что может быть причиной?

Answer (score 2):

По-умолчанию, все методы в Visual Studio подсвечиваются жёлтым цветом. Подсветка методов `MonoBehaviour` синим - это одна из особенностей интеграции Unity с Visual Studio.

*Вот похожий вопрос на англоязычной ветке: [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519368/in-visual-studio-my-method-name-is-colored-blue-instead-of-white).*